# Envelope of family of curves $x(u,v)=\cos^2(u)\cos(v)+\cos(u)\sin(u)\sin(v)$, $y(u,v)=\cos^2(u)\sin(v)-\cos (u)\sin(u)\cos(v)$

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

How to generally find singular solution or envelope of a two parameter family of curves $ x(u,v),y(u,v) $ in the plane?

The parametric equations

$$x(u,v) = \cos^2 (u) \cos (v) + \cos (u) \sin (u) \sin (v),\\
 y(u,v) = \cos^2 (u) \sin (v) - \cos (u) \sin (u) \cos (v),\\
 (0 < v <  2 \pi), (0 < u < \pi ),$$

represent rotating circles of unit diameter passing through the origin and rotating about the origin. How do we obtain their envelope $ x^2+y^2=1 ? $

EDIT1:

The envelope is $x^2+y^2==1 $ as shown below.

EDIT 2:

We can wlog write $v = c $ for any rotated position.

$$x(u,c) = \cos^2 (u) \cos (c) + \cos (u) \sin (u) \sin (c),\\
 y(u,c) = \cos^2 (u) \sin (c) - \cos (u) \sin (u) \cos (c).\\ $$

[image: CirclesPassing_thro'Center]

I think that I know the C-discriminant method with *one parameter*, but would like to know how to extend it to *two parameters*.

Can it be extended to 3D space to find a surface envelope?

Comment: The equation $x^2+y^2=1$, represents a circle in 2-space (or possibly a cilinder in 3-space). It is not related to the graph you gave. You should elaborate on what everything stands for. Are we in the xy-plane, xyz-plane? Etc...

Comment: What are your parameters, for instance? As it is, $u$ and $v$ are both variables.

Comment: A parameter is not only a fixed quantity in an equation in your present understanding. It has another mathematical connotation. A surface or area is generated by variation of parameteric variables. Yes, In this case $u,v$ are parameteric variables. As a matter of fact, the plot is generated in Mathematica ParametricPlot.

Comment: I think you want $0\leq u,v$ in stead of "$<$" BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understood you correctly, we have  the curves $\gamma_v(u):(0, \pi)\to\mathbb R^2$, given by:
$$\gamma_v(u)=\begin{pmatrix}x_v(u)\\y_v(u)\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2 (u) \cos (v) + \cos (u) \sin (u) \sin (v)\\
  \cos^2 (u) \sin (v) - \cos (u) \sin (u) \cos (v)\end{pmatrix}$$
and we are looking for the envelope of the family $\{\gamma_v(u)\mid v\in [0,2\pi)\}$.

I believe that you already found that each $\gamma_v(u)$ describes the circle $$\left( x-\frac12 \cos(v)\right)^2+\left( y-\frac12\sin(v)\right)^2=\frac14.$$

We now convert to the implicit form
$$F(u,v)=\left( x-\frac12 \cos(v)\right)^2+\left( y-\frac12\sin(v)\right)^2-\frac14=0.$$ 
Note that $(0,0)$ lies on $F(u,v)=0$, for every $v$.

We can now find our envelope by solving:
$$\begin{cases} F(u,v)=0\\ \\ \dfrac{\partial F(u,v)}{\partial v}=0\end{cases}$$
You can easily check that $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v}=x\sin(v)-y\cos(v).$ So we find that points lie on our envelope, if and only if, it is an intersection point of the circle $F(u,v)=0$ and the line $x\sin(v)-y\cos(v)=0$, for some $v$.

Since we can easily see that $\left(\frac12 \cos(v), \frac12 \sin(v)\right)$ (the centre of $F(u,v)=0$) always lies on the line $x\sin(v)-y\cos(v)=0$, we infer geometrically (see picture) that the envelope is:
$$(0,0)\cup \left\{ (x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\right\}.$$
Note how the origin should be included in the envelope.

> [image: The forming of the envelope of a family of circles rotating around the origin]
>
> <sup>$\color{red}{\text{The circles $F(u,v)=0$ (red)}}$;
>
>   The line $x\sin(v)-y\cos(v)=0$;
>
>   $\color{blue}{\text{The envelope (blue)}}$.</sup>

The same result can be derived using algebraic methods, but this is a lot more writing.

Comment: z=0 everywhere. We are in the plane, The graph clearly shows envelope The small circle $ ( x- \frac12)^2 +y^2 = \frac14^2  $ passes through the origin. When it is rotated about origin what results is the big circle envelope $ x^2 +y^2  =1. $

Comment: @Narasimham But how do you describe the circles. You need some parameter $c$, such that there is a curve assosiated to each value of $c$. This is not the case. For each $u$ and each $v$ you are describing a point. You can only get the circle $(x-\frac12)^2+y^2=\frac1{16}$ if you fix $v=0$ and look at the graph of $F_v(u)=\big(x(u,0),y(u,0)\big)$. The family $\{F_v(u),v\in[0,2\pi)\}$ is a one-parameter family of curves (parameterised by $v$). This has an envelope and I can explain to you how to find it (not today). Is that what you want?

Comment: My typo the small circle is $(x−1/2)^2+y^2= 1/4 $

Comment: :)   We can wlog write $v = c $.

Comment: @Narasimham I edited the answer. I believe this is what you wanted.

Comment: I put in u =0 or u= constant, Now partially differentiate wrt v and eliminate v....is this the procedure valid *for all such* problems?

Comment: I accepted your answer, but hope you still address the generalization question above.

Comment: Does [this post of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710000/145141) help you get a clear view of things?

Comment: No, it does not. It is not relevant in a complete sense.  If x,y, are dependent coordinates, my question is for $two$ independent parameters You have here only one independent parameter $t$.  I suggest you take an other example and plot the 2D locus.